# Raise error in case if json object has missing keys in post request

Tags: spring, kotlin

I am sending a json in my post request. I want to raise an friendly error in case if any keys is missing.

```
@PostMapping("/copy")
    fun post(@RequestBody user: User): String {

        log.debug("Received a request")
        return "hello"
    }


data class User(
     val name: String,
     val age: Int
)
```

So my question is if I post a request and if post data like:
{"age":23} then I get a response saying bad request "name is not defined".

Can anyone share some thoughts here? How should I handle such cases? I do not want to write if else in the post request as my data will be very big and there will be many keys which will be essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see. Try this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException::class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
fun handleError(exception: HttpMessageNotReadableException): String =
    exception.mostSpecificCause.message ?:exception.localizedMessage
```

Output should be as follow:

> Parameter specified as non-null is null: method hex.adapter.Example$User., parameter name

To format it as ""name is not defined" you can write:

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException::class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
fun handleError(exception: HttpMessageNotReadableException): String =
     exception.mostSpecificCause.message
             ?.split("parameter ")
             ?.get(1)
             ?.let { "$it is not defined" }
             ?:exception.localizedMessage
```

Answer (score 0):

Your User class should allow nulls:

```
data class User(
     val name: String?,
     val age: Int
)
```

val name should be Maybe-String type (String?), not String.

Comment: It does not give me an error if I do not pass name , I want to raise an error if any key is missing from the json data